# Scaling MySQL database, increasing performance to many connections

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, database-performance, query-performance

I have a monitoring system where my customers can register their terminals and his terminals send a periodically (5min) keepalive signal to my website to inform that it is online. customers also can access a monitoring page that show all his terminals and update it's status using ajax in an interval of 20sec.

**Plus information:** a terminal is a android device, customer have to install an app from google play.

**THE PROBLEM IS:**
With increasing customer number, many peoples access the monitoring page at the same time that is almost flooding server with many requests, and on the other side. each time more terminals is comming and flooding more with it's keepalive signal. so I have besides the common pages (login, many CRUDs etc) dozens phisical terminals sending keepalive signal through internet flooding my database, and many users accessing monitoring pages to get informed their terminals are online. it seems like a time bomb. because I don't know if mysql will support when number of terminals reach hundreds and counting.

**PLUS** we're already noting our server is decreasing performance along the time it is running. We restart it, and it's very fast, but along the time, it will lose performance

**SOLUTION**

- What can I do to improve performance or make the model more scalable? there is an design pattern for this kind of monitoring system that is more scalable?
- There is any gain if I separate two mysql databases, one for common use (access pages, cruds etc) and another for monitoring system?
- There is any gain to use MongoDB just for the monitoring part of the system?

**additional information:**

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

PHP 5.4.40 (cli) (built: Apr 15 2015 15:55:28)

Jetty 8.1.14 (for java server side that comunicates with android app)

**Server Mon**

```
Free memory ........: 17.84 Gb

Total memory........: 20 Gb

Used memory.........: 2.16 Gb

RAM.................: 20 Kb

JVM Free memory.....: 1.56 Gb

JVM Maximum memory..: 3.93 Gb

JVM Total available.: 1.93 Gb

**************************************

Total (cores).: 10

CPU idle......: 4.9%

CPU nice......: 0.0%

CPU system....: 4183000.0%

CPU total.....: 5.0%

CPU user......: 2.6%

**************************************

Total space (bytes)..: 600 Gb

Free space (bytes)...: 595.64 Gb

Usable space (bytes).: 595.64 Gb
```

**PART OF MODEL AND MONITORING PAGE'S QUERY**

**This is terminals table**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GM_PLAYER` (
      `ID_PLAYER` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `DS_GCM_ID` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
      `DT_CRIACAO` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `DS_PLAYER` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      `DS_JANELA_HEIGHT` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1024',
      `DS_JANELA_WIDTH` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '768',
      `DS_JANELA_POS_X` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `DS_JANELA_POS_Y` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `DS_WALLPAPER` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `FL_ATIVO` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
      `FL_FULL_SCREEN` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
      `FL_MOUSE_VISIBLE` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
      `DS_SERIAL` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `VERSAO_APP` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `VERSAO_OS` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `FL_EXIBIR_STATUS_BAR` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
      `ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `ID_CLIENTE` BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
      `ID_PONTO` BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
      `FL_ATIVO_SISTEMA` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
      `FL_DEBUG` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
      `VERSAO_APP_UPDATE` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
      `FL_ESTADO_MONITOR` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'L',
      `FL_DEVICE_ROOTED` CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N',
      `DT_ATIVACAO` DATETIME ,
      `DT_EXPIRA` DATETIME ,
      `FL_EXCLUIDO` CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N' ,
      `ID_USUARIO` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `ID_PACOTE` BIGINT UNSIGNED ,

      `DS_IMG_BARRA` VARCHAR(255),
      `FL_EXIBIR_HORA` CHAR(1),
      `DS_TEXTO_BARRA` TEXT,

      PRIMARY KEY (`ID_PLAYER`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_GM_PLAYER_ID_PLAYER` (`ID_PLAYER` ASC),
      INDEX `ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` (`ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` ASC),
      INDEX `FK_GM_PLAYER_GM_CLIENTE_idx` (`ID_CLIENTE` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_GM_PLAYER_GM_USUARIO` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO`) REFERENCES `GM_USUARIO` (`ID_USUARIO`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `FK_GM_PLAYER_GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO`) REFERENCES `GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` (`ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `FK_GM_PLAYER_GM_CLIENTE` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CLIENTE`) REFERENCES `GM_CLIENTE` (`ID_CLIENTE`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    )
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

**another used tables**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GM_CLIENTE` (
      `ID_CLIENTE` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `DT_CRIACAO` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `DS_CLIENTE` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `FL_ATIVO` ENUM('S','N') NULL DEFAULT 'S',
      `ID_CONTATO` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `ID_ENDERECO` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID_CLIENTE`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_Cliente_ID_CLIENTE` (`ID_CLIENTE` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_GM_CLIENTE_GM_CONTATO1_idx` (`ID_CONTATO` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_GM_CLIENTE_GM_ENDERECO1_idx` (`ID_ENDERECO` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_GM_CLIENTE_GM_CONTATO1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CONTATO`)
        REFERENCES `GM_CONTATO` (`ID_CONTATO`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_GM_CLIENTE_GM_ENDERECO1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`ID_ENDERECO`)
        REFERENCES `GM_ENDERECO` (`ID_ENDERECO`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

    CREATE TABLE GM_USUARIO_CLIENTE ( 
        ID_USUARIO_CLIENTE INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
        ID_CLIENTE  BIGINT UNSIGNED ,
        ID_USUARIO  BIGINT UNSIGNED
    );
```

**This is the table where I update every time I receive a new terminal keepalive signal**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GM_LOG_PLAYER` (
      `id_log_player` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `dt_criacao` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `id_player` BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
      `qtd_midias_exibidas` INT(11) NULL,
      `id_ultima_midia_exibida` BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
      `up_time_android` bigint(20) unsigned default '0',
      `up_time_app` bigint(20) unsigned default '0',
      `mem_utilizada` BIGINT(20) NULL,
      `mem_disponivel` BIGINT(20) NULL,
      `hd_disponivel` BIGINT(20) NULL,
      `hd_utilizado` BIGINT(20) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_log_player`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_id_log_player` (`id_log_player` ASC),
      INDEX `FK_GM_LOG_PLAYER_GM_PLAYER_idx` (`id_player` ASC),
      INDEX `FK_GM_LOG_PLAYER_GM_MIDIA_idx` (`id_ultima_midia_exibida` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_GM_LOG_PLAYER_GM_PLAYER`
        FOREIGN KEY (`id_player`)
        REFERENCES `GM_PLAYER` (`ID_PLAYER`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `FK_GM_LOG_PLAYER_GM_MIDIA`
        FOREIGN KEY (`id_ultima_midia_exibida`)
        REFERENCES `GM_MIDIA` (`ID_MIDIA`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 3799
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` (
      `ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `DT_CRIACAO` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `DS_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `ID_USUARIO` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO_ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` (`ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO_GM_USUARIO1_idx` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO_GM_USUARIO1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO`)
        REFERENCES `GM_USUARIO` (`ID_USUARIO`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 3
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

**This is the query executed periodically through ajax requests to update monitoring page**

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT
            LOG.id_log_player ,
            LOG.dt_criacao ,
            DATE_FORMAT (LOG.DT_CRIACAO , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') F_DT_CRIACAO ,
            (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - LOG.DT_CRIACAO) AS IDADE_REGISTRO ,
            LOG.qtd_midias_exibidas ,
            LOG.id_ultima_midia_exibida ,
            LOG.up_time_android ,
            LOG.up_time_app ,
            LOG.mem_utilizada ,
            LOG.mem_disponivel ,
            LOG.hd_disponivel ,
            LOG.hd_utilizado ,
            PLA.FL_MONITOR_LIGADO,

            CLI.DS_CLIENTE ,

            PLA.ID_PLAYER id_player ,
            PLA.DS_PLAYER ,
            PLA.ID_CLIENTE ,
            PLA.VERSAO_APP ,
            PLA.FL_ATIVO PLA_FL_ATIVO ,
            PLA.ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO ,
            PLA.FL_DEVICE_ROOTED ,
            PLA.DS_GCM_ID ,
            PLA.FL_HDMI_LIGADO ,

            -- IF(PLA.FL_ATIVO='N',0,IF(PLA.ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO IS NULL,0,IF(PLA.ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO='0',0,1))) ATIVO,
            IF(PLA.FL_ATIVO='N',0,1) ATIVO,
            DATE_FORMAT (LOG.DT_CRIACAO , '%Y%m%d%H%i%s') TIME_STAMP_CRIACAO ,
            DATE_FORMAT (LOG.DT_CRIACAO , '%d/%m às %H:%i') F_DT_CRIACAO_MIN ,
            -- (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - LOG.DT_CRIACAO) ESPERA_NOVA_COMUNICACAO ,
            --GRA.ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO GRA_ID_GRADE ,
            GRA.DS_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO GRA_DS_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO,
            MID.DS_PATH_THUMB THUMB_ULTMID
        FROM GM_PLAYER          PLA
        LEFT JOIN GM_CLIENTE CLI USING ( ID_CLIENTE )
        LEFT JOIN GM_USUARIO_CLIENTE GUC USING ( ID_CLIENTE )
        LEFT JOIN GM_LOG_PLAYER         LOG USING ( ID_PLAYER )
        LEFT JOIN GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO GRA USING ( ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO )
        -- LEFT JOIN GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO GRA ON ( PLA.ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO = GRA.ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO )
        LEFT JOIN GM_MIDIA              MID ON ( LOG.ID_ULTIMA_MIDIA_EXIBIDA = MID.ID_MIDIA )
        WHERE PLA.ID_USUARIO = ?
        AND PLA.FL_EXCLUIDO = 'N'
        AND PLA.FL_ATIVO = 'S'
        ORDER BY LOG.DT_CRIACAO DESC
    ) TBALL
    GROUP BY ID_PLAYER
    ORDER BY PLA_FL_ATIVO DESC , DT_CRIACAO DESC
```

**EXPLAIN QUERY ABOVE (taken from development database)**

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                                        | key                                          | key_len | ref                                  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                                                 | NULL                                         | NULL    | NULL                                 | 37752 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | PLA        | ALL    | NULL                                                 | NULL                                         | NULL    | NULL                                 |    44 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | CLI        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,UQ_Cliente_ID_CLIENTE                        | PRIMARY                                      | 8       | imidiatv.PLA.ID_CLIENTE              |     1 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | GUC        | ref    | fk_GM_CLIENTE_has_GM_USUARIO_GM_CLIENTE1_idx         | fk_GM_CLIENTE_has_GM_USUARIO_GM_CLIENTE1_idx | 8       | imidiatv.PLA.ID_CLIENTE              |     1 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | LOG        | ref    | FK_GM_LOG_PLAYER_GM_PLAYER_idx                       | FK_GM_LOG_PLAYER_GM_PLAYER_idx               | 9       | imidiatv.PLA.ID_PLAYER               |   858 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | GRA        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,UQ_GM_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO_ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO | PRIMARY                                      | 8       | imidiatv.PLA.ID_GRADE_PROGRAMACAO    |     1 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | MID        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,UQ_GM_MIDIA_ID_MIDIA                         | PRIMARY                                      | 8       | imidiatv.LOG.id_ultima_midia_exibida |     1 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many terminals are sending keyalives?  (From which I can compute how many queries/second that contributes.)  Similarly for the monitoring.  And what does the monitoring `SELECT` look like?  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: I'm fishing for (1) Is it so many qps that that is the problem, or (2) Is it that the queries are inefficient and should be improved.

Comment: @RickJames, Good morning! 
Today I have only about 80 terminals but I expect it support around a thousand in one year. 
SELECTs and CREATE TABLE you requested is now on the post

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer...

One aspect of scaling is to minimize the disk footprint so that caching will be more effective.  Toward that end, here are some suggestions:

```
  PRIMARY KEY                     (`id_log_player`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_id_log_player` (`id_log_player` ASC),
```

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key, so the latter is redundant and wasteful of disk space and `INSERT` time.  `DROP` it.

`INT` is 4 bytes; `BIGINT` is 8 bytes.  `ID_xx INT UNSIGNED` can handle up to 4 billion values; do you really need to go beyond 4 billion?  In InnoDB, each secondary key contains a copy of the `PRIMARY KEY`, meaning that an unnecessary `BIGINT` PK consumes a lot more space.

Your tables are `latin1`; are you limiting the App to western languages?  If you change to utf8 (or utf8mb4), I will point out wasted space for `CHAR(1)`.

Please perform `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` with the tables as they stand; then make some of the changes below and do the `EXPLAIN` again.  I'm thinking that the difference may be dramatic.  I expect the part dealing with

```
    LEFT JOIN GM_USUARIO_CLIENTE GUC USING ( ID_CLIENTE )
```

to be quite 'dramatic'.

If `GM_USUARIO_CLIENTE` is a "many-to-many" mapping, ...

- Get rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT`; instead use `PRIMARY KEY(ID_CLIENTE, ID_USUARIO)` to save some space and make it more efficient.  (And if you do go beyond 4 billion CLIENTEs, etc, the `INT` would not suffice!)
- Add two indexes so that lookups will be much faster. (1) the PK (above), and (2) the other direction: `INDEX(ID_USUARIO, ID_CLIENTE)`.  Without those, `JOINs` involving that table will be slower and slower as you scale.

Date arithmetic is not this simple:

```
(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - LOG.DT_CRIACAO)
```

Study the manual page on date functions; it is more complex to subtract `TIMESTAMP - DATETIME`.  If you will be spanning timezones, be careful which datatype you use for what.

I see this pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ...
    ORDER BY ...    -- ??
    ) x
GROUP BY ...
```

What were you hoping to achieve?  The optimizer is free to ignore the `ORDER BY` in the subquery.  (Although, it may actually be performing it.)

Don't use `LEFT` unless you have a reason for it.

This clause

```
    WHERE PLA.ID_USUARIO = ?
      AND PLA.FL_EXCLUIDO = 'N'
      AND PLA.FL_ATIVO = 'S'
```

would benefit (greatly?) from `INDEX(ID_USUARIO, FL_EXCLUIDO, FL_ATIVO)`.  The order (in this case) of the columns in the index does not matter.  If those two flags are changing frequently, do not include them in the `INDEX` -- `UPDATEs` might be slowed down more than `SELECTs` would benefit.

Those were the easy-to-spot suggestions.  `EXPLAIN` may help spot more suggestions.  And do you have other `SELECTs`?

I said "partial solution".  Was that `SELECT` the "monitoring select"?  Let's also check the periodic `UPDATEs`.

Comment: Rick James, Periodic updates are just updates to GM_LOG_PLAYER that update almost only the terminal status, date of log and some ids/flags. this update is not done by PHP side. I have to ask for Java programmer to give me the query, but the explain I taked from development database and going to add on my comment

Comment: The monitoring is scanning all log entries for all players each time?  That seems excessive.  And there are hundreds, maybe thousands, of log entry for each player?  The problem is with the _design_ of the monitoring.  You need to fetch fewer log entries or fewer users each time the monitoring is fetched.

Comment: The LOG can keep a history of activity; that's ok.  But have another table that gives you the _current_ state for each player -- _one_ row per player.  When you `INSERT` into the LOG, `UPDATE` this new table to reflect the current state.  That redesign will give you 100-fold improvement in scalability.

Comment: the line WHERE PLA.ID_USUARIO = ? will filter by user, I just get all logs from one user, not for all users. first implementation, terminals did inserts on database. but it was filling our database of old useless data, so we change it to just update, today, each terminal have just one line on GM_LOG_PLAYER table. and it's updated on each keepalive signal. We don't care about history at this moment.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Does it run faster with 1 user & 1 log row?  Suggest adding updated info to your question, or mark this thread as solved rather than clutter it confusing EXPLAINs, etc.

Comment: (It would be good to change the table from "log" to "status" since it now functions differently.)